# re.match returns memory error in python

Tags: python, out-of-memory

```
def name():

    with open('newfile.txt') as f:
        lineno = f.readlines()

    for line in lineno:
        h = re.compile('(#DESIGNATION\ \:[\n\t]*)((.)*[\n\t]*)*?\#')
        print h.match(line)

name()
```

newfile.txt contains about 100 lines. When run this program give error `MemoryError`. While removing ? from `'(#DESIGNATION\ \:[\n\t]*)((.)*[\n\t]*)*?\#`', gives no error. Why is this happening and what are feasible solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: Try moving the `h = re.compile(...)` outside of the loop

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert.py", line 38, in <module>
    name()
  File "insert.py", line 33, in name
    print h.match(line)
MemoryError

Comment: @BrentWashburne Not solved. still same error

Comment: How big is the file you're reading in bytes?

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: @KurtStutsman 5973 bytes

Comment: What do you expect `*?` to achieve?

Comment: @Jasper a line start with #DESIGNATION and matches all lines till get first #. like (\#DESIGNATION :)[.\n\t]*?# but it is not working.

Comment: @cdarke ?# i.e. greedy #

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that your regular expression similar to the regex `((.)*)*?` which I think will cause an explosion of matching groups. You also say you're trying to match multiple lines, but you're only search on a single line at a time because of `f.readlines()` and `for line in lineno`

Comment: @piyush-balwani: `*?` non-greedy `*`, i.e. zero or more of the preceding group, preferably as few as possible (including zero).  Quantifiers quantify what is to their left..

Comment: @cdarke [http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html] tells that ? is also a greedy operator.

Comment: @KurtStutsman yes it seems to be possible.

Comment: @piyush-balwani: `?` has two uses.  If you had `#?` it would mean zero or one (optional) `#`, preferably one (greedy).  If `?` follows a quantifier it marks it as non-greedy.  Read "Laziness Instead of Greediness" in the reference you gave.

Comment: @cdarke thanks cdarke. now its clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match "#DESIGNATION :" followed by some lines followed by a line with a "#" at the beginning, you first need to read the text in as a single string and use `re.MULTILINE` to match it. Here is an example:

```
import re

text = '''
cat
mouse
#DESIGNATION : horse
dog
bird
lake
#
ocean
sea
#DESIGNATION : bike
box
table
#
nothing
something
'''

h = re.compile('^#DESIGNATION :(?:[^\n]|\n[^#])*\n#', re.MULTILINE)
matches = re.findall(h, text)
print repr(matches)
```

which outputs

```
['#DESIGNATION : horse\ndog\nbird\nlake\n#', '#DESIGNATION : bike\nbox\ntable\n#']
```

Note that I'm using the `(?:)` match operator here to group regexes together without capturing their matched text each time it is evaluated.

With a larger file you probably wouldn't want to have re match the entire text body at once and iterate through the lines instead. If you do that, though, you cannot use '\n' in the expression because you will only be working with a single line at a time. Instead you would need to maintain state of if you're in a #DESIGNATION block or not.